# Laravel 5: How to copy (stream) a file from Amazon S3 to FTP?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, ftp, laravel-5.5, laravel-filesystem

I have to move large content, which I don't want to put into memory from AWS S3 to FTP with Laravel's filesystem.

I know how to stream local content to S3, but haven't found a solution yet from S3 to FTP.

The closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182712/2852047), but I'm stuck in adapting it for my case.

Here is what's missing in my code (??):

```
$inputStream = Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->??
$destination = Storage::disk('ftp')->getDriver()->??

Storage:disk('ftp')->getDriver()->putStream($destination, $inputStream);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think I found a solution:

```
$input = Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver();
$output = Storage::disk('ftp')->getDriver();

$output->writeStream($ftp_file_path, $input->readStream($s3_file_path));
```